# Most performant/efficient way to pass live data between components every frame?

Tags: components, aframe, communication

I've made two components: one renders a flying sprite, in effect a light-source; the other is a general-purpose lens-flare generator. Each frame/tick, the sprite moves on a bit, and the lens-flare component needs to know where in world-space it's moved to (a vector, three float values) so it can calculate where to draw the flares. I've got it working, but the way I'm doing it feels wrong. This is what it looks like: https://youtube.com/shorts/iFizKIF6saI

*Note that the moving light-source/sprite component's **entity's position** stays fixed at the centre of its flight path* (not least because there's some particle stuff going on too), so its attributes don't get updated. Within the component itself there are local coordinates being updated, and I need to communicate them over to the lens-flare component.

There seem to be a number of ways of getting this kinda live data from one component to another:

a) **using component attributes** - the data stuff in the components' schema. The light source could update x, y and z attributes each frame, and the lens-flare component could read them back each frame. Doing this seems to update the DOM, though - you can see the numbers updating in real time in your browser's Web Inspector - which feels like an unnecessary performance hit.

b) **emitting events** - the light source could emit an event each frame, containing its new position. This, again, seems inefficient - firing events and listening for events seems like a lot of machinery for something I know needs to happen every single frame.

c) **using global variables** - this is the way I'm doing it in the example above: the light-source updates window.tx / ty / tz each frame, and the lens-flare component reads them. It feels a little naughty to be using window.blah variables for this.

d) **... other ways?**

I don't mind that the components in this case are tied together in this way, rather than being turned into configurable general-purpose components - really just want to know what the most efficient way to handle this "live data from one thing to another" thing would be.

Any thoughts/tips appreciated :)